# How to using SharedPreference in ToggleButton Android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, alarm, togglebutton

im using 3 toggle button to set alarm at 6 AM, 12 PM and 6 PM, but alarm only on at 6 pm, or Last time on the third time :(
Alarlm on only at method `public  void startEnamSore() {`

The Code :

```
public class AlarmFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private TextView textViewEnamPagi, textViewDuabelas, textViewenamSore, textResult;
private ToggleButton toggleButtonEnamPagi, toggleButtonDuaBelas, toggleButtonEnamSore;

public AlarmFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment AlarmFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static AlarmFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    AlarmFragment fragment = new AlarmFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);



    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm, container, false);
    toggleButtonEnamPagi = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    //textViewDuabelas = (ToggleButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
    textViewEnamPagi = (TextView)   v.findViewById(R.id.textViewalarm);
    textViewDuabelas = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    toggleButtonDuaBelas = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
    textResult = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewhasil);
    toggleButtonEnamSore = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.toggleEnamSore);

    textViewEnamPagi.setText("OFF Pukul 06.00 AM");
    textViewDuabelas.setText("OFF Pukul 12.00 PM");

    startSix();
    startDuaBelas();
    startEnamSore();

    toggleButtonEnamPagi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(toggleButtonEnamPagi.isChecked()){
                textViewEnamPagi.setText("ON Pukul 06.00 AM");
                SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(1);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edt = preferences.edit();
                edt.putBoolean("tgEnam", true);
                edt.commit();
            }else {
                textViewEnamPagi.setText("OFF Pukul 06.00 AM");
                SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(1);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edt = preferences.edit();
                edt.putBoolean("tgEnam", false);
                edt.commit();
            }
        }
    });

    toggleButtonDuaBelas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(toggleButtonDuaBelas.isChecked()){
                textViewDuabelas.setText("ON Pukul 12.00 PM");
                SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edt = preferences.edit();
                edt.putBoolean("tgDuabelas", true);
                edt.commit();
            }else{
                textViewDuabelas.setText("OFF Pukul 12.00 PM");
                SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edt = preferences.edit();
                edt.putBoolean("tgDuabelas", false);
                edt.commit();
            }
        }
    });

    toggleButtonEnamSore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(toggleButtonEnamSore.isChecked()){
                //textViewDuabelas.setText("ON Pukul 12.00 PM");
                SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edt = preferences.edit();
                edt.putBoolean("tgEnamsore", true);
                edt.commit();
            }else{
                //textViewDuabelas.setText("OFF Pukul 12.00 PM");
                SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edt = preferences.edit();
                edt.putBoolean("tgEnamsore", false);
                edt.commit();
            }
        }
    });



    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
return v;
}



public void startSix(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean tgenam = preferences.getBoolean("tgEnam", true);
    if(tgenam == true){
        textViewEnamPagi.setText("ON Pukul 06.00 AM");
        toggleButtonEnamPagi.setChecked(true);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();          
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), MyReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity().getApplication(), 0, myIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
       // }
    }else{

    }

}
public  void startDuaBelas() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean tgduabelas = preferences.getBoolean("tgDuabelas", true);
    if (tgduabelas == true) {
        textViewDuabelas.setText("ON Pukul 12.00 PM");
        toggleButtonDuaBelas.setChecked(true);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();           
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), MyReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity().getApplication(), 0, myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        // }
    } else {
        textViewDuabelas.setText("OFF Pukul 12.00 PM");

    }
}


public  void startEnamSore() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean tgenamsore = preferences.getBoolean("tgEnamsore", true);
    if (tgenamsore == true) {
        toggleButtonEnamSore.setChecked(true);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();         
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), MyReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity().getApplication(), 0, myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        // }
    } else {


    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: what you mean ? unable to understand your problem ...
What I got is you set the three alarm but only 3rd one Alarms at the specific time ?

Comment: really, please rework your question, it´s confusing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that all alarms should Alarmed at their specific time Then you need to change the Id of the pending indent ... these should be different so the Alarm manager can distinguished between them.

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity().getApplication(), unique_id, myIntent, 0);
```

instead ...

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity().getApplication(), 0, myIntent, 0);
```